# My program keeps generating four times?

Tags: java, arrays, random

For some reason when i run this program instead of outputting one card choice I get 3, sometimes four.

I'm trying to pick a name from the array list include it in the path, then output the image, you can see the result with the system out.

Heres the code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    Main.createScreen();

}

public static void createScreen() {

    JFrame p = new JFrame("Angora Realms");
    p.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GameGUI g = new GameGUI();
    p.add(g);
    p.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    p.pack();
    p.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Here's where i create the GUI and also the paint:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public Button drawCard = new Button("Draw Card");

public GameGUI() {
    drawCard.addActionListener(this);
    add(drawCard);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    Object cause = event.getSource();

    if (cause == drawCard) {
        System.out.println("Ay");
        repaint();
    }
}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Cards c = new Cards();
    g.drawImage(c.getImage(), 0, 0, 450, 700, this);
    }
}
```

And here is where i choose what card to load:

```
public class Cards {

static Random random = new Random();

public static String getCard() {

    String card = null;
    String[] possibleCards = new String[] {"Cheetah", "Lion"};

    card = possibleCards[random.nextInt(2)];
    System.out.println(card);

    return card;

}

public Image getImage() {

    Image img = null;

    try {
    img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/dev/angora/images/plains/" + Cards.getCard() + ".png"));
    } 
    catch (IOException e)  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return img;
}

}
```

When I run the code I get 4 system print outs of a random variation of Cheetah and Lion. I've been told before that I'm actually creating 3 instances of my code somewhere, but I have no idea where...

Comment: Probably doesn't answer your question, but don't do file I/O in the paintComponent() method. The painting methods should be for painting only.

Comment: @camickr, how else could i input a variable into the graphics method? I wouldn't be able to do "paint(image);"

Comment: Painting may occur at any time for any reason, rather then placing the logic for determine which image to load in the `paintComponent` method, do it within you `actionPerformed` and store the result in instance variable, which can be used by the `paintComponent` method to render the image...

Comment: Wow uhhh, that solved the problem!

Comment: You need to take a look at and understand [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't entirely get to decide how and when `paintComponent()` gets executed, and that usually doesn't matter, because all the method is supposed to do is to *paint the component*. It gets called when you do a `repaint()`, but it also gets called when Swing *thinks* the UI needs to get updated (which can be when the window changes focus, it gets resized or a bunch of other reasons).

However, you've given it some responsibility that it shouldn't have—to instantiate `Cards`.

Move `Cards c = new Cards();` from `paintComponent()` into `actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)` where it belongs and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> how else could i input a variable into the graphics method?

In general, you have a setter method and then you save the data as an instance variable in your class that the painting method can reference.. This is how methods like setBackground(...), setForeground(...), setFont(...) work.

So maybe you have a method like `drawCard(...)` in your class that will get a random card and set your "image" instance variable. Then you invoke repaint() in the drawCard() method so the component can repaint itself.

The component, not the application should be responsible for painting itself when a property of the component changes.